# substring() throwing Unhandled Exception

Tags: c++, substr, size-t

I am trying to make a simple program that helps the user learn to type quickly. It prints a character, and the user should press it quickly to "win".

I'm getting a runtime error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x772A33D2 in Learn To Type Quickly.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00FEF138. occurred

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    while (true)
    {
        int r = rand() % 26;
        string length = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        size_t found = r;
        size_t sz = 1;
        string sub = length.substr(length.at(found),sz);
        cout << sub << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the use of `at()`. `substr` wants the position, not a character.

Comment: at() is returning the char value of the character at that position - which is greater than the size of the string. Hence the exception.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) takes an **index** as input, but you are passing in a **character** that was retrieved from a given index.  The value of that character is being *misinterpreted* as an index, and all of the characters in your string have [numeric values](http://www.asciitable.com) (97..122) that are higher than the `size()` of your string (26), so `substr()` throws a `std::out_of_range` exception:

> **Exceptions**
>
> `std::out_of_range` if `pos > size()`

When calling `substr()`, you need to replace `length.at(found)` with just `found`:

```cpp
//string sub = length.substr(length.at(found),sz);
string sub = length.substr(found,sz);
```